# Stored procedure in Redshift to load data into a table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, sql-insert

I have a sql query which fetches the data from 4 tables and I want to use this script to load data into another table in Redshift and I am trying to create a stored procedure but I keep getting errors. Below is my script.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE ABC1 (SOURCE_SYS CHAR(3), FILE_NBR BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SP1 (SOURCE_SYS,FILE_NBR)
  VALUES(
    SELECT 'WT', PK_ORDERNO
    FROM table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_1.file_nbr = table_2.file_nbr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_3 ON table_2.file_nbr = table_3.file_nbr
  )
END;
```

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO SP1(...) SELECT ... FROM ...` (so there is no `VALUES()`). Still, it is quite unclear what you are trying to do. It seems like the query does not actually uses the arguments of the procedure. Please provide sample data, desired result, and an explanation of your purpose.

Comment: I have 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2. Now i have created another table Tablenew. This tablenew will get the data from a sql statement that joins table1 and table2. Now i want to create a sp to insert the data into tablenew.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC1 (SOURCE_SYS CHAR(3),FILE_NBR BIGINT)
AS $$
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO SP1 (SOURCE_SYS,FILE_NBR)

    SELECT 'WT',PK_ORDERNO FROM 
    table_1 join table_2 on table_1.file_nbr=table_2.file_nbr
    left outer join
    table_3 on table_2.file_nbr = table_3.file_nbr ;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I get the below error.[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";